# gdb batch set breakpoint on everywhere caller of some function

Tags: gdb

I have a snippet of code like this.

```
void caller1() {if(cond1())return;else foo();}

void caller2() {foo();}

void caller3() {foo();}


void foo(void) {return;}
```

There are a function named `foo` and some callers named `caller1`, `caller2` and `caller3`.The name of callers don't have any rules to obey.

I do not want to set breakpoints many times on every caller, but to batch set breakpoints.

Is there any convenient GDB command? Any help is appreciated.

FYI:
As to why I have this thought, I am unable to set a breakpoint on `foo` sometimes when `cond1()` happens and `foo` isn't always called by `caller1`.

Comment: Something like [`rbreak caller`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html#index-rbreak)?

Comment: but what if the caller's name doesn't have a rule to obey?

Comment: Then you're probably out of luck.

Comment: GDB can set breakpoints on function entry and at the beginning of lines that have executable code and at specific machine-code addresses. For each of your examples, where do you want the breakpoint to be?

Comment: The beginning line of every caller is ok for me. Or else any position of caller is yet ok. I wonder how to set breakpoints on frame 1(callers) according to the stack caller chain.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want to set breakpoints many times on every caller, but to batch set breakpoints.

There is no way to achieve what you want.

Your only option is to use something like `objdump -d a.out` to collect all the functions where `foo` is called, and then set a breakpoint on each such function.

You don't have to do that manually though: with text processing you can construct a list of such functions, put them into a "command file", and source that file from GDB.

P.S. http://xyproblem.info may be relevant here: *why* do you care to set a breakpoint on `caller1()` if it's not *actually* going to call `foo()`?